# Getting an error Undefined function and undefined variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, user-accounts

I am trying to code using PHP. PHP syntax confused me that's why I am having an error. I am trying to display the information listed on the database to my profile webpage but I am not sure if I am getting it right.

This is my table inside database:

[image]

Below is the PHP code:

```
<?php
require('db.inc.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
  header('Location: login.php');
}

$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_account where email ='$email'  "; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)
{
$firstName = $row('firstName');
$lastName = $row('lastName');
$sex = $row('sex');
$email = $row('email');

}
                                                    
?>
```

Here is the Body code:

```
    <body > 
    <div class="container bg-white" id="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 login-form pl-0 pr-0" style="background-image:fixed">
                                <img class="card-img-top center-block" src="photos/account-icon2.png" alt="image"> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class=" pt-5">
                                        <h1 class="text-primary">Your Information</h1>
                                        <br>

                                        <h5>First Name</h5>
                                        <h3><?php echo $firstName;?></h3><br>
                                        <h5>Last Name</h5>
                                        <h3><?php echo $lastName;?></h3><br>
                                        <h5>Sex</h5>
                                        <h3><?php echo $sex;?></h3><br>
                                        <h5>Email Address</h5>
                                        <h3><?php echo $email;?></h3><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <form action="logout.php">
                                        <button type="submit" name="logout" class="btn btn-danger btn-block w-25 rounded pull-right" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to logout?');">Log Out</button>
                                    </form>        
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>                
</body>
```

Any answer will help, so I can improve my skill.

Comment: Is this academic code for learning, or for production use with real users?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: it is only academic code. just want to explore sir @tadman

Comment: If you’re just getting started with PHP development and want to make applications, pick a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your style and needs. These come with many examples that illustrate how to do exactly what you’re asking for here.

Answer (score 1):

In the line below, the parentheses are forgotten

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

Change it to the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Comment: This is a tiny bandage on a huge problem.